# Select2 on asp.net server controls?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-select2

I'm trying for some time to use Select2 in my projects but I can't make it to work as I want. I develop asp.net webforms apps, so what I need is to be able to pick the selection result at code behind after a post.
The problem is that whatever I do I always get my textboxes text fill with something like "[object OBJECT]" instead of the text being shown at the page.
I guess that I'm not giving the control the apropiate data format, but I can't find the problem.

That is currently throwing me away from using it. So I only need a little omph to start with select2.

My example code is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=Codigo.ClientID%>").select2({
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            quietMillis: 2000,
            ajax: {
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/api/Search/Customers")%>',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return {
                        "$filter": "substringof(tolower('" + term + "'), tolower(Name))",
                        page_limit: 10
                        //"$skip": page * 10,
                        //"$top": 10
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    return { results: data }; //, more: true
                },
                params: {
                    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
                }
            },
            id: function (d) { return { id: d.Id }; },
            formatResult: function (d) {
                return d.Name;
            },
            formatSelection: function (p) {
                return p.Id;
            },
            formatNoMatches: function () {
                return "No results found. (Case Sensitive)";
            },
            escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; },
            dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop",
            initSelection: function (element, callback) {
                var id = $('#<%=hdnCodigo.ClientID%>').val(); //$(element).val();
                if (id !== "") {
                    $.ajax('<%=ResolveUrl("~/api/Search/Customers/")%>' + id, {
                        dataType: 'json'
                    }).done(function (data) { callback(data); });
                }
            }
        }).select2("val", $('#<%=hdnCodigo.ClientID%>').val());

        $('#<%=Codigo.ClientID%>').change(function () {
            $('#<%=hdnCodigo.ClientID%>').attr("value", $('#<%=Codigo.ClientID%>').select2('data').Id);
        });
    });
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="Codigo" class="input-medium" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCodigo" runat="server" />
```

It's some example copied, and I don't know if all that code around the hidden field is needed for getting an initial value or existing values between postbacks.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Thanks to Moshtaf I was able to get my selected Id with small modification to his code. I also completely discarded the HiddenField.

```
...
            initSelection: function(element, callback) {
                var id = $(element).val();
                if (id !== "") {
                    $.ajax('<%=ResolveUrl("~/api/Search/Customers/")%>' + id, {
                        dataType: 'json'
                    }).done(function(data) { callback(data); });
                }
            }
        }).select2("val", $('#<%=Codigo.ClientID%>').val());

        $("#<%=Codigo.ClientID%>").change(function () {
            $(this).val($(this).select2('data').Id);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The only problem left is that after the postback, for a small moment appears the selected Id, but suddenly disappears and the control becomes empty.
Sure it's something wrong with the line:

```
}).select2("val", $('#<%=Codigo.ClientID%>').val());
```

But I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as i understand you can using select2 without any problem and you can get ajax results as a dropdownlist and select them in your output, but the only problem is that you can't get selected value (or values) in codebehind. if my assume is correct so you have a textbox and a javascript code like this:

```
strSelect2FieldId = "#<% = TextBox1.ClientID%>";
$(strSelect2FieldId).select2({
    //Your Config
});
```

If you want to access the selected value(s), add this code:

```
$(strSelect2FieldId).change(function () {
    var strSelectedValues = (JSON.stringify($(this).select2('data')));
    $(this).val(strSelectedValues);
});
```

then call TextBox1.Text in codebehind easily and you can see the selected value(s) as a JSON string.

If i'm misunderstanding your question, please tell me to provide you more information and details, i have some experience about select2 in asp.net and i use this plugin in several projects and several cases and it's so powerful.

Comment: thanks for your aid. Yes, my texbox is called "Codigo" in my example. And I was able with that code to fetch ajax response from a new web api controller and with odata functionality. So that's why $filter appears there.
Thanks for your pointing me in the right direction, I was able to get the selected value in my code behind. Please look at my modifications. If you also could help me to retain the selected data after a postback would be wonderful. I also would like to see more of your select2 coding, specially for cascaded country-state-city selectors, and share knowledge.

Comment: If you was able to get the selected value in your code behind, so what's the problem in this question?
If you have more questions that not related to this topic, you can create separate topic for each one because discussing about all of them is a little difficult in Comments section.